# Limit Easy Tables queries to Rows with Provided UserID

Tags: sql, express, azure-web-app-service

So I'm starting a new series of apps based on some apps I made for my company internally. With my company's apps (that I also used Azure web app to host the API and SQL), I didn't have to limit query results in any particular way because there was only 1 user, so no risk of any users getting access to data they weren't supposed to have.

But now that I'm modifying these apps for external use, I obviously will only want each user to query each table for rows that they should have access to.

My first idea was to just not allow normal EasyTable access at all, but to just expose everything through carefully built APIs, each of which will require a UserID as a parameter to work at all.

This option is fine to me, but I'm not sure if it's the right thing to do, or if there's a way to still allow for normal EasyTable access while still allowing each user to only have access to their own rows on each table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have authentication set up against Azure Active Directory, Facebook, Google, Twitter, Microsoft Account, or other OAuth login providers, then you can set permissions on tables to restrict access for specific operations to only authenticated users like below:

[image]

For more information, review [How to: Use authentication claims with your tables](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/blob/master/articles/app-service-mobile/app-service-mobile-node-backend-how-to-use-server-sdk.md#how-to-use-authentication-claims-with-your-tables).

About how to limit the data so that the logged in user can see just their records, check out this [really good tutorial](https://shellmonger.com/2016/04/11/30-days-of-zumo-v2-azure-mobile-apps-day-6-personal-tables/).

Comment: I'm marking your answer as correct even though it isn't necessarily what I'm going to do in practice. I'll post an answer of what I'm actually going to do, as I don't want to use Identity Providers in my case.

Comment: Btw even though I'm not directly using your answer, those links you provided gave a load of information about how I will implement it in the end. Thanks a lot brother.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I don't want to use Identity Providers, I want my app to provide its own authentication against an email address.

I'm going to have a User table, which I'm going to basically just disable access to through the normal OData API. I'm going to provide an API where a user can feed an email address and a password, and if it matches, my API will feed back the ID of that row (which is some long ridiculous string). The user application will then be able to use that ID to access the other tables.

For access to all my other tables, through the normal OData API, [I can use the 'context' object to look at HTTP headers](http://azure.github.io/azure-mobile-apps-node/global.html#context). Given that HTTPS headers are encrypted, I feel that this is a relatively safe option. All the table methods will require an HTTP header of something like `[${vendor-prefix}-UserID] = UserID`.

On the client side, I often use the MobileServiceClient library, which [allows addition of custom headers](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/appserviceteam/2016/06/16/adjusting-the-http-call-with-azure-mobile-apps/), so I can add the header there when required.